# Conversion Linker tag not working when setting cross-domain tracking using AMP variable

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up cross-domain tracking for my AMP pages. I'm using Google Tag Manager to implement the "Conversion Linker" tag. Here is the problem I'm experiencing:

- When I fill the "Auto Link Domains" attribute of the "Conversion Linker" tag by directly entering the list of domains, cross-domain tracking works fine and I can see the linker params decorating the URLs when moving from the AMP pages to the other domain.
- The problem is that I can't enter the list of domains directly, I need to fill the "Auto Link Domains" attribute by using a GTM AMP variable. The AMP page has a variable that lists the domains. When I use the variable to populate the attribute cross-domain tracking does not work. Here's a screenshot: [AMP Conversion Linker tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFcSI.png)

I have already confirmed that the AMP variable is pulling the information correctly. I even tested setting up the "Auto Link Domains" attribute of the Conversion Linker by using a simple GTM Constant where I set up the domains, and not even that works.

I'm thinking it could be a bug or limitation of the "Auto Link Domains" attribute.

Has anyone tried this?

Thanks in advance!!
G

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this question. I was able to find a workaround that solves the issue for my scenario. Instead of relying on AMP variables (pulled from the AMP pages) to set up the "Auto Link Domains" attribute in the AMP Conversion Linker, I set the "Auto Link Domains" attribute to "[asterisk].[asterisk]" this enables cross-domain tracking for any domains linked from my AMP pages.

Still, the question remains, why can't I set the "Auto Link Domains" using an AMP variable? This seems like a bug to me.

Thanks!
G